# Simplifying a Fraction with Limit 0

Tags: limits, logarithms

i have a problem understanding the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{e^{\sqrt[5]{\ln(n)}}}= 0$$

Could someone expand this for me so i can see, why this converges to zero?
As far as i know, both terms diverge to $\infty$. The Denominator clearly diverges faster than the nominator, but i cant think of a simplification of this fraction to make it look trivial, that this term converges to zero.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t = \ln^{\frac{1}{5}}(n)$. Then, for $n \to \infty$, also $t \to \infty.$
As a consequence:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{e^{\sqrt[5]{\ln(n)}}}= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{t^5}{e^{t}}= \lim_{t \to \infty} t^5 e^{-t} = 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Take the substitution $n:=e^{x^5}$ as $x\to+\infty$ then you obtain:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{e^{\sqrt[5]{\ln(n)}}}&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac {x^5}{e^x}\\
&=0.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: $0$ ok but directly (skipping the line containing this strange $5!$).

Comment: This is the consquence of the L'Hopital's rule. @AnneBauval

Comment: Why "factorial of $5$"?